# referencing functions with pointers

Tags: c

> (int ( * ) (void*, void*))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp));

numcmp and strcmp are functions with two arguments.

I understand what the conditional operator is doing. That is straightforward.

I can reason that this will evaluate to numcmp(void*, void*) or strcmp(void*, void*), but I don't understand why? Particularly, the:
 int (*), confuses me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do function pointers in C work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: Are you asking why the syntax is the way it is (so awkward)?

Comment: Side note: calling the resulting pointer is UB. `strcmp`'s parameters aren't `void*`, neither are `numcmp`'s (otherwise the conditional wouldn't compile). Of course, that's exactly the compiler error that you get if you don't shut it up with that cast.

Comment: I didn't know that you could cast something to an entire function including its arguments. Coming from java, we just casted obects/variable types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `(int ( * ) (void*, void*))` is just a cast to a function pointer with two `void*` arguments returning `int`. As for other casts, the syntax resembles a variable declaration without variable name. Then depending on the boolean switch, it is decided which of the functions to cast.